# Detecting if letter is equal to "X" in Keras

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to learn Keras and trying something very simple. I have created a dataframe with 200.000 random letters with two columns. letter and is_x. is_x is set to 1 (or True) if letter is capital "X".

Here's what i did so far:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
#model.compile(optimizer=SGD(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.05), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=10, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
results = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
y_predict = model.predict(X_test)

print(results)
print("---")
for i in y_predict:
    print(i)
```

and here's the results:

```
[0.09158177]
[0.09158175]
[0.09158177]
[0.09158177]
[0.09158175]
[0.09158177]
[0.09158173]
```

What I'm trying to get is 1 or 0 if is_x is True. I sşmply feed letter as X_ and is_x as y_ however i only get some numbers and they are all look same like 0.996 and etc. Also accuracy is something like 0.99 but it's far away from the reality.

I'm very confused about activation and optimizer and loss. I couldn't understand which to choose and how to solve this simple problem. I have studied lots of training videos on udemy but noone explains why and how they use these functions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really answer the optimizer and activation piece very effectively but I can provide some assistance with the other parts. tanh and relu are both pretty popular activation functions so you should be fine with either of those. Likewise, Adam is an effective optimizer so you should be fine on that level.

Loss Function should be `binary_crossentropy` in your problem. This is used when you have two classes to learn (0/1). `categorical_crossentropy` is used in the case of multiclass problems and `mse` is useful for regression analyses. The objective of the algorithm is to minimize the value of this function. Thus you need to choose the appropriate one for the problem at hand.

Your accuracy is very high. A major reason for this is that you have uneven sample sizes between is x and is not x. All an algorithm has to do in order to achieve a really high score is predict 'not x' for everything.

In order to assess your model a little bit more, try this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
# this will remove the probabilities and give 1/0
y_predict = (y_predict > .5)

# this will create a confusion matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predict)
```

This makes it easier to view the model accuracy by showing you how many times it predicted x and the actual result was x, how many times it predicted not x and the actual result was not x, along with the mislabeled cases.

```
       predicted
         not x       x
not x      #         #
  x        #         #
```

Using this tool you can assess how accurate your model was in a better way.

Comment: Now i get something like this     [[14134     0][  847     0]]. Why do you use 0.5 ? It's always more than 0.50

Comment: I would need more information to really assess this. That piece of code: `y_predict = (y_predict > .5)` sets a boundary at .5 and says anything higher than that should be a 1, anything lower a 0. I believe that the numbers you are showing are the index (14134) and the predicted group for that specific case (0). When you say the value is always more than .5, are you talking about the y_predict value or the results value?

Comment: Well it changes as i change Adam's lr. So i don't think this is the problem in my case.

Comment: Also there's something i don't understand. Why does confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predict) give me this weird results? [[14134 0][ 847 0]]

Comment: Ohh, that's the confusion matrix. I understand now.

That means that it correctly predicted 14,134 cases as not x, and incorrectly predicted 847 cases as not x when there was an x.

See my above example of the confusion matrix. `[[14134 0]` is the first line, `[847 0]]` is the second.

Moral of the story: it's saying that everything is not x as a means of maximizing accuracy. It is failing to detect x

Comment: is_x is set to 1 if letter is X else it's 0. But it should predict some... I mean i don't think it can not predict any of it?

Comment: Sure it can. That's exactly what it is doing. Based on the information you have provided it, it is not "learning" anything that allows it to make a prediction. These algorithms are 'dumb'. They aim to cut corners where possible and yours found an easy way to maximize accuracy: pick not x for everything and get an accuracy of .943.

Comment: ah got it. So isn't it possible to predict x? :)